# Using PHP, Ajax and JavaScript to put data from every row in my database into a separate div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database table with an `id`,`name` and `city`. I am trying to put a **name** and **city** into a div for each row in the table. This is my html:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script> 
     function ajax_post(){
       var list= document.getElementsByClassName("something");
       // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
       var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
       var url = "load.php";
       var cnt= list.length;
       var coun= "count="+cnt;
       var fn = "";//document.getElementById("first_name").value;
       var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&count="+cnt;



        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded        variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
           hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

           var nlist= document.getElementsByClassName("bname");
           var clist= document.getElementsByClassName("cname");

           for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

               var u=1;
               var t=0;

            var parts = hr.responseText.split("----Seperator----");
            var one = parts[0];
            var two = parts[1];
            nlist[i].innerHTML=parts[0];
            clist[i].innerHTML=parts[1];

            } 

        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars,coun); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

}
</script>


</head>
<body>


<input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>


<div id="h0" class="something">
    <div id="n1" class="bname"> </div>
    <div id="c1" class="cname"> </div>
</div>
<div id="h1" class="something">
    <div id="n2" class="bname"> </div>
    <div id="c1" class="cname"> </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

this is my php code :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $newcnt = $count + 1;

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("testing_ajax");

    for ($in = 0; $in < $newcnt; $in++) {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,city FROM table1 WHERE id LIKE('$in%')");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $name = $row["name"];
            $city = $row["city"];
            $id = $row["id"];
            echo $name . "----Seperator----" . $city;
        }
    }
?>
```

the result that i am getting is, that on presing submit it just draws from the first row and puts the first name, city into both of the divs.

im trying to get it to print the first row(daniel, bray) in the first div and the second row(niamh, greystones) in the second div. 
really appreciate any help you guys have <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON to send arrays instead of strings:

JSON is a cross-language (based on JS) array format: http://json.org/

PHP:

```
$array = Array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){


    $name = $row["name"]; 
    $city = $row["city"];  
    $id=$row["id"];


    $array[] = array("name" => $name, "city" => $city)

}

echo json_encode($array); //echo "[{"name":"n1","city":"NY"},{"name":"n2","city":"Paris"}, ...]
```

And js:

```
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

       var nlist= document.getElementsByClassName("bname");
       var clist= document.getElementsByClassName("cname");

       var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText); //we parse the list and get an array

       for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

           var parts = data[i]
           var one = parts["name"];
           var two = parts["city"];
           nlist[i].innerHTML=one;
           clist[i].innerHTML=two;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are my hero sir, thank you <3 its exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're passing only 2rows from php 
and trying to assign them to `div` if that's right then you have a problem here

```
nlist[i].innerHTML=parts[0];
clist[i].innerHTML=parts[1];
```

Your returned output would be like `name1 ---seperator--- city1---seperator--- name2 ---seperator--- city2` the `parts` will have 4 elements but you are using only `0,1` so try to replce that with `i`

try:

```
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

               var u=1;
               var t=0;

            var parts = hr.responseText.split("----Seperator----");
            var one = parts[0];
            var two = parts[1];
            nlist[i].innerHTML=parts[i];
            clist[i].innerHTML=parts[i];

            }
```

Though that will solve your problem..you logic is too complicated what you're trying to do can be easily achieved like:

> PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $newcnt = $count + 1;

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("testing_ajax");

    for ($in = 0; $in < $newcnt; $in++) {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,city FROM table1 WHERE id LIKE('$in%')");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $result[]=(object)array($row["name"],$row["city"]);
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
?>
```

and loop over this json in script and create html dynamically

Comment: And what if my name is   `----Seperator----` ? We don't know what is in the database... So If my name is `----Seperator----`, there will be beautiful bugs